# Force routerlink to refresh component

Tags: angular

I have created a very basic angular 5 application.

I have a left menu which is always displayed (it is part of asp.net core2.0 mvc project skelton with bootstrap).

I have created 2 links in this menu:

```
          <li>
            <a [routerLink]='["/component/1"]'>Component 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a [routerLink]='["/component/2"]'>Component 1</a>
          </li>
```

As you can see, the 2 links points to the same route (same component). We just have the id which changes. Here is the route line in app.module.ts

```
  { path: 'component/:id', component: MyComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

I have added some log in my component typescript class:

```
constructor()
{
    console.log("constructor");
}

ngOnInit()
{
    console.log("ngOnInit");
}
```

If i click on the first link, everything works great. But if i click to second link, my component is not reloaded. There are no calls to constructor or ngOnInit. If i click on another link which loads another component and then return to the second link, it works.

What i want to do is how can i force angular to reload component when i click on a link which points to the same component than the one actually displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Normally in this case, you don't reload the component. Rather, you watch for changes in the required route parameter and proceed accordingly.

In my application, I use something like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            const id = +params['id'];
            this.getMovie(id);
        }
    );
}
```

This code catches ever change to the route parameter and causes my `getMovie` method to be executed every time the route parameter changes.

For a complete example, check out: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter

Comment: Thanks.  You are a live saver.  I spent two days looking for a solution.  This was so simple.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

Comment: If I have a menu and I want to achieve the same, should I add that code in the menu component, or in the component that I want reloaded? Thanks!

Comment: in the father component ;)

But this isnt necesary now, you can change in the route and the var that contains the page ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Deborah works best for your case where we only have to look for changes in the queryParams.

For anyone else, if your project really requires re-rendering a component as mine did(maybe you require to call ngOninit to reevaluate something), it can be done with

```
constructor(private router: Router){
     // override the route reuse strategy
     this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
        return false;
     }

     this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
           // trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
           this.router.navigated = false;
           // if you need to scroll back to top, here is the right place
           window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

The thread to the discussion where I found the solution : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Frederick Montiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70602045/5018771) was helpful to me but uses a now deprecated syntax, so here is a version for Angular 16:

Implement a `RouteReuseStrategy`:

```js
import { BaseRouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NoRouteReuse extends BaseRouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

And use it in your `main.ts`:

```js
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { NoRouteReuse } from '@config/no-route-reuse';

...

    providers: [
       ...,
       { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: NoRouteReuse }
    ]

...
```