# Ionic 7 / Angular 15: NG01000 Errror

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

Please note that I have researched this error at several place but unable to fix it.  That is why posting here.

I am seeing the following error for a form.  I have tried several things such as setTimeout, ChangeDetector and AfterInit but nothing is solving this issue.  Below is my code:

ERROR Error: NG01000: There are no form controls registered with this group yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).

```
if (this.postData.token) {
        this.detailService.getDetails(this.postData).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {

                let userid = this.authUser.user_id;

                this.form.setValue({
                firstname: res[0].firstname,
                lastname: res[0].lastname,
                email: res[0].email,
                phone: res[0].phone,
                relationship: res[0].relationship,
                userid: userid
                });

          return this.detail = res;
        },
        (error: any) => {
          this.toastService.presentToast('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
        }
      );
    }
```

Below is my HTML code

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<ion-item  lines="none" class="ion-margin itemDesign">
  <ion-icon
          name="person-outline" slot="end" color="medium">
        </ion-icon>
  <ion-input label="First Name" autocomplete="off" name="firstname" type="text" ngModel required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item  lines="none" class="ion-margin itemDesign">
  <ion-icon
          name="person-outline" slot="end" color="medium">
        </ion-icon>
  <ion-input label="Last Name" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="lastname" ngModel required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item  lines="none" class="ion-margin itemDesign">
  <ion-icon
          name="mail-outline" slot="end" color="medium">
        </ion-icon>
  <ion-input label="Email" autocomplete="off"  type="email" name="email" ngModel required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item  lines="none" class="ion-margin itemDesign">
  <ion-icon
          name="phone-portrait-outline" slot="end" color="medium">
        </ion-icon>
  <ion-input label="Phone" autocomplete="off"   name="phone" type="tel" ngModel></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item  lines="none" class="ion-margin itemDesign">
  <ion-icon
          name="people-outline" slot="end" color="medium">
        </ion-icon>
  <ion-input label="Relationship" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="relationship" ngModel></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="userid" ngModel></ion-input>
```

I have also tried the form tag as:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="confirm(myForm.value)">
```

```
Code with ngAfterViewInit that was originally in ngOnInit.

 ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.auth.userData$.subscribe((res: any) => {
         this.authUser = res;
         let user_id = this.authUser.user_id;
         this.getDetail();
   });
  }
```

```
Addition information:  instead of using routerLink to redirect back to the list page, I am using the following code.  The reason behind this is because my list was not updating after creating a new item or updating an existing item.  My routing through refresh, it shows an updated list.  With routerLink this error doesn't show.

 redirect() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('refresh', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['home/settings/detaillist']);
         }, 0);
    });
   }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share when you place the `if (this.postData.token)` logic? Have you tried placing in the [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) method? Also share what is `form`? Are you using Angular Template form or Reactive form?

Comment: Its placed in function called getdetail()  which is called in ngOninit.  I will try placing it in ngAfterViewInit and see if it can be resolved.

Comment: @YongShun Wrapping in ngAfterViewInit() didn't help.  I have added the code above for your reference.

Comment: @YongShun. Please additional context.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue of using routerLink with the following question. 
 But would be nice to see a solution for Ng01000 error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446261/force-routerlink-to-refresh-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR Error: NG01000: There are no form controls registered with this group yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).

You have declared a form on the html:

> ```
> <form #myForm="ngForm">
> ```

But where is this being declared in the ts file? No where from what you shown. This needs to be declared and initialized. The docs show example on how to properly do this: https://angular.dev/guide/forms/reactive-forms#overview-of-reactive-forms

Comment: That didn't work.   I think thats because my forms are template driven forms.

Comment: the answer still applies, you still need to declare and initialize the template form in which you have not shown in your code. check the docs for template driven form.